# resolve objectDTO in http.post angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an http.post with (http client) and I'm trying to resolve an object (the result in json converted to that objectDTO)

I'm using this `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

```
login(user: UserLogin): Promise<UserPOJO> {
        return new Promise<UserPOJO>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.serviceProvider.login().then(
                response => {
                    resolve(this.http.post(this.apiurl + '/users', serialize(user), { headers: headers})
                        .map(????)
                        .toPromise());
                }).catch(err => reject(err));
        });
    }
```

I do not know that yo do in `map` I'd like to add the object deserialized into an objectDTO.

Note I'm using a JsonProperty on my UserPOJO as follows

```
@JsonProperty('jsonkey')
  ....
```

My goal

I'd like to return an object deserialized something like this `return deserialize(UserPOJO, user);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in a less convoluted manner, thanks to the beauty of promises:

```
login(user: UserLogin): Promise<UserPOJO> {
    return this.serviceProvider.login().then(response =>
        this.http.post<UserPOJO>(this.apiurl + '/users', serialize(user),
                      { headers: headers })
        .toPromise();
    );
}
```

if you return a `Promise` inside `then`, the promise returned by `then` resolves or reject to the same value as that inner promise, so you don't need to create a new one by calling `new Promise`. I'm assuming your `/users` service already returns a `UserPOJO` object, so you don't need to use `map`, just cast the result type using generics.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Doesn't work, @Oscar Paz, do you know another way to return the resolve of UserPOJO?

Comment: Why does it not work? Are you getting an error? Or are you receiving something different?